Where to put my own shell scripts and configuration files?
Could anybody explain, in which directory (or directories) I should place my own shell scripts and configuation files on macOS?

/usr/local/bin/?
/usr/local/etc/?
$HOME/bin/?
$HOME/etc/?
... ?

A best practice or a most common way?
Example files are:

webpage2pdf.zsh - an ImageMagick script to convert a webpage to PDF
.webpage2pdf - a configuration file for it
.zshrc_my-own - a Zsh cofiguration file that is  sourced in my ~/.zshrc using source, as suggested by Gilles to avoid accidental overridings: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/787409


It's really about your own convenience. If you are creating artifacts that you will publish via git-hub or others, you should use any convention you find for those (I don't know what that would be). For strictly personal code it should just be that when you are looking to change something 1 yr later, you know where to find it (-;!

Mentioning this for completeness: I've started seeing python's pip using $HOME/.local/bin (as well as ~/.local/etc and .../share and .../man) when doing user leve installs. I think this is a neat idea, but as an addition to storing your personal scripts in $HOME/bin . This lets the installation tools manage ~/.local/bin, and you manually manage ~/bin.  Similar to the difference between /bin and /use/local/bin.
And remember to put both in $PATH variable.

@JeremyImpson I know this is silly, but I'm somewhat obsessed about filenames. If that directory in $HOME will contain not only scripts but also configuratiion files, is it correct to name it usr, that is: $HOME/usr? A directory that contains scripts and configuration files that I manage manually. And I don't mean to create bin or etc directories inside it.

AFAIK, the only thing approaching a true standard is the FHS (File Hierarchy Standard). It's not been updated in nearly 10 years now, but perhaps its maintainers felt no changes have been needed since then. For Apple systems, you might want to peruse this document... scroll down a bit to find the material pertinent to macOS. This documentation is also old, but as Apple's documentation generally is either poor or nonexistent, this is well above average for them! :)  But speaking of poor documentation, the Linux Foundation has not done a superb job either; for example, see the "Other Links" at the bottom of this page.
So yeah - guidance on the various filesystem hierarchies is rather spotty. And some of the guidance that does exist in the form of standards is not precise. IOW, prepare yourself for some ambiguity.
All that said, perhaps the best, most succinct guidance may likely be found on your macOS from the terminal: simply enter man hier (alt. an online version):

/usr/local/    executables, libraries, etc. not included by the basic operating system

Finally, you probably shouldn't overlook the possibility of using $HOME/bin for (at least some of) your scripts. I seem to recall that at least one Linux distro (Debian) now automatically adds $HOME/bin to your PATH env variable (if it exists; via ~/.profile). You could do something similar on your macOS.

/etc usually stores configuration files.
/usr/local will be separated from your $HOME, so if one day you decide to backup $HOME to save your own files, these scripts will not be copied.
I'd just go with $HOME/bin, don't forget to add it to your $PATH.
